What is the environmental impact of using Github Copilot
This may be an unanswerable question, at least for anyone outside Microsoft, but is there any way of finding out the ballpark carbon footprint per query of using Github Copilot (or similar tools)?
Context
Many of us believe that it is essential to reduce our CO2 output, and a lot has been said recently about the high environmental cost of AI (discussed here amongst other places).  That said, if Copilot (and similar tools) are able to provide a solution much more quickly than finding the solution by traditional means then they could end up being carbon negative (discussed here).
I am about to start a trial of these tools at work, and one metric that I want to measure is the environmental impact - but I can't find any per-query metrics (or, indeed, any metrics) on the CO2 emissions of Github Copilot (OpenAI Codex / GPT-3).
How frequently does it need to be retrained (which will be necessarily expensive), how many queries are executed against a particular version of a trained model, and what's the cost of making an individual query to the model (excluding training costs).
It's a minefield, but a minefield I fear we will need to traverse if we truly want to assess the value of these new tools.
Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?


any per-query metrics

OpenAI Codex / GPT-3 are closed source, so unless OpenAI/MSFT released/leaked CO2 stats, we can't know. CO2 stats for opensource models have been estimated, e.g. {1}.

References:

{1} Luccioni, Alexandra Sasha, Sylvain Viguier, and Anne-Laure Ligozat. "Estimating the carbon footprint of bloom, a 176b parameter language model." Journal of Machine Learning Research 24, no. 253 (2023): 1-15.

